# Using an Angular filter with an adjacent component

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using angular 1.6.4 I'm unable to use a filter on an ng-repeat across an adjacent component.  In the example I've created a component for the dynamic listing of data (ng-repeat) and then a separate component for the search input.  I can't figure out how to pass the data from the search component to the keyfeed component.

### app.js

```
app.component('keyfeed', {
  bindings: { 
    search: '='
  },
  template: `
    <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="record in records | filter:search">{{ record }}</li>
    </ul>
  `,
  controller: function($scope) {
    $scope.records = [
      "Alfreds Futterkiste",
      "Berglunds snabbköp",
      "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
      "Ernst Handel",
    ];
  }
});

app.component('search', {
  bindings: { 
    search: '='
  },
  template: `
    <input type="search" search="$ctrl.search" ng-model="search">
  `,
  controller: function() {
  }
});
```

### index.html

```
<search search="search"></search>
<keyfeed search="search"></keyfeed>
```

Plunker: [view](http://plnkr.co/edit/5Bw293yIo2fv71NRRclx?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `$ctrl` you need to perform the actual bindings in the templates.

```
<li ng-repeat="record in records | filter:$ctrl.search">{{ record }}</li>

<input type="search" ng-model="$ctrl.search">
```

[See the updated plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/noX5CZz7oOEyTuFfq7iF?p=preview)

Comment: Ahh, so close.  Thanks!